# How do I specify column name and types while extending ActiveRecord::Base in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Forgive my ignorance if I am missing something really trivial, I am very new to *RoR*.

Coming from *Django* background I remember models being like

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
```

both column name and field type are clearly specified.

Where as, when I write this rails command

```
> rails g model Post title:string description:text
```

all I get is

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title
end
```

**Is there a way to write column names and field types while extending `ActiveRecord::Base` instead of having them only in the migration file?**

Thanks, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

attr_accessible is deprecated and strong params replaces it functionality in the controller.

If you want to get a list of the schema information in your model file you can annotate it at the top of the file.  This was best practices at some point, however I do not think it is used as much.  I personally do not like this and just use the schema.

Post on best practices and annotating:
http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/68-annotate-your-models

Gem to auto annotate:
https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models

Comment: Do you mean there is no way in rails to do it, I mean I know I can comment, but there's no rails syntax to do that?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this.  Even if there is a way you should not do it in Rails.  It would be stepping way outside of the golden path.  What is the problem with using a migration?

If you really would like to set something in the model you can use alias_attribute.  You will need to have an already existing column name though.

alias_attribute :new_column_name, :real_column_name

Answer (score 0):

The most wonderful thing about ActiveRecord is that you don't need to do any mapping, as all the fields are being automatically mapped using current schema. Of course default mapping can be overridden if needed, however this is a very rare case.

This approach is called "convention over configuration" and is present all over Rails - it assumes most common parameters for what you are trying to achieve so it saves a lot of unnecessary coding and mapping. It might feel weird at start, especially that you'll need to learn how to override those defaults, but I promise you are gonna love it when you get used to it. :)